# Parameter Pack with alternating types

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, variadic-templates, pack

I have a `struct C` which gets initialized with a variable number of instances of `struct A` and `struct B`. E.g.:

```
struct A
{};

struct B
{};

struct C
{
    C(A&& o1, B&& p1, A&& o2)
    {}
    C(A&& o1, B&& p1, A&& o2, B&& p2, A&& o3)
    {}
    C(A&& o1, B&& p1, A&& o2, B&& p2, A&& o3, B&& p3, A&& o4)
    {}
    C(A&& o1, B&& p1, A&& o2, B&& p2, A&& o3, B&& p3, A&& o4, B&&p4, A&& o5)
    {}
};
```

So, rather than providing multiple ctor's with different number of parameters I would like to find something generic.
However, the number of ctor parameters always grows about two parameters: `B&&` and `A&&`.
Could this be accomplished using parameter packs. Or would be another solution without implementing for each number of parameters an according ctor?

The goal should be that `struct C` can be constructed like the following examples:

```
C c1 = { A(), B(), A() };
C c2 = { A(), B(), A(), B(), A(), B(), A() };
```

etc.

Comment: Does the number of parameters need to be known at compile-time? In any case consider passing `std::pair<A, B>&&`s instead.

Comment: During compile time would be the sugar on the top. However, the approach with std::pair had some problems (as I tried it): the expression looks a little weird C c = { A(), { B(), A() } }; and so far I wasn‘t able to hyve something txpesafe with a variable number of params.

Comment: Actually I thought this initialization syntax is better, because it clearly shows which two arguments belong together. What do you mean by `typesafe`? You can make sure that the template parameters are as expected with `static_assert` or SFINAE if you need other overloaded constructors.

Comment: Actually, the syntax would be more clear without curly braces in between. I‘m not very familiar with SFINAE, sounds I should learn more about it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a variadic template and SFINAE to enable only the constructor where the type parameters satisfy your (or any arbitrary) condition.

```
#include <type_traits>
struct A {};
struct B {};
```

You need `type_traits` for `std::false_type` and `std::true_type`.

The `alternates` template is the key. The goal is to make `alternates<X, Y, T1, T2, T3, ..., Tn>` inherit from `std::true_type` if and only if the `T1`, ... `Tn` list is alternating `X` and `Y`. The default choice (just below) is *no*, but we specialize for matching cases.

```
template <typename X, typename Y, typename... Ts>
struct alternates : std::false_type {};
```

I choose to make this template more generic than your requirement here and allow `alternates<X, Y>` to inherit from `true_type`. The empty list satisfies the mathematical requirement that all elements of it alternate. This will be a good stopgap for the recursive definition below.

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
struct alternates<X, Y> : std::true_type {};
```

Any other list of `alternates<X, Y, Ts...>` alternates if and only if `Ts...` minus the first element alternate `Y` and `X` (`Y` first!).

```
template <typename X, typename Y, typename... Ts>
struct alternates<X, Y, X, Ts...>
: alternates<Y, X, Ts...> {};

struct C
{
```

We define the constructor as a template that first takes a parameter pack (the type will be deduced, no need to specify when calling) and it has a defaulted template parameter for SFINAE purposes. If the defaulted argument cannot be calculated based on the parameter pack, the constructor will not exist. I added the extra conditions about the number of pairs which I assumed from the example.

```
    template<typename... Ts,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<
            sizeof...(Ts) % 2 == 1 &&
            sizeof...(Ts) >= 3 && // did you imply this?
            alternates<A, B, Ts...>::value
        >::type>
    C(Ts&&...);
};
```

The way [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) works is that `std::enable_if` only defines the `std::enable_if<condition, T>::type` (the `::type` part) if `condition` is true. That can be any arbitrary boolean expression computable at compile time. If it is false, saying `::type` at the end will be a *substitution failure* and the overload where you tried to use it (e.g., `C{A(), A(), A()}`) will simply not be defined.

You can test that the examples below work as expected. The ones commented out are not expected to work.

```
int main() {
    C c1 { A(), B(), A() };
    C c2 { A(), B(), A(), B(), A(), B(), A() };
    // C c3 {};                     // I assumed you need at least 2
    // C c4 { A(), B(), A(), A() }; // A, A doesn't alternate
    // C c5 { B(), A(), B() };      // B, A, B not allowed
    // C c6 { A(), B(), A(), B() }; // A, B, A, B doesn't pair
}
```

[Try the code here.](https://godbolt.org/z/gVZdr0)

Comment: I like this answer. One thing you can improve is that you don't need `std::conditional`: `template <typename X, typename Y, typename... Ts>
struct alternates<X, Y, X, Ts...>
: alternates<Y, X, Ts...> {};`

Comment: I can't wait for compile-time reflection so that we can write type checks like this without using all these unreadable partial specialization-based techniques.

Comment: @Brian Might that also result in nicer error messages if I make the effort? I especially didn't like the error message of `C c = {}`: `could not convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>()' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'C'`

Comment: @palotasb: You could write another ctor that has a `!enable_if` and then fails a `static_assert` on the interior

Comment: You can remove one specialization by using `template <class, class, class... Ts> struct alternates : std::integral_constant<bool, !sizeof...(Ts)> {};`. Also consider whether implicit convertibility might not be *good enough*.

Comment: @AndyG thanks, good idea!
@Deduplicator I prefer the mathematical purity of `alternates` meaning that the pack alternates the first two parameters -- just as the name says. Requiring that there are at least 1 (...or two? three?) elements is a separate concern even if the total lines of code are a bit more.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you can use a template delegating constructor

Something as follows

```
#include <utility>

struct A {};
struct B {};

struct C
 {
   C (A &&)
    { }

   template <typename ... Ts>
   C (A &&, B &&, Ts && ... ts) : C(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)
    { }
 };

int main()
 {
   C(A{});
   C(A{}, B{}, A{});
   C(A{}, B{}, A{}, B{}, A{});
   C(A{}, B{}, A{}, B{}, A{}, B{}, A{});
 }
```

If you require at least three element (so no `C(A{})` but at least `C(A{}, B{}, A{})`) the not-template constructor become

```
   C (A &&, B &&, A&&)
    { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would help...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

// Simple classes A & B to represent your alternating pattern classes.
class A{ public: int a; };
class B{ public: int b; };

// helper class template to act as a single parameter kind of like std::pair...
template<typename T, typename U>
class Pack{
private:
    T t_;
    U u_;

public:
    Pack( T&& t, U&& u ) : 
      t_( std::move( t ) ),
      u_( std::move( u ) )
    {}

    T getT() const { return t_; }
    U getU() const { return u_; }        
};

// your class with varying amount of parameters for its ctors
template<class T, class U>
class  C{
private:
    std::vector<Pack<T,U>> packs_;

public:
    template<typename... Packs>
    C( Packs&&... packs  ) : packs_{ std::move( packs )... } { }

    std::vector<Pack<T,U>> getPacks() const {
        return packs_;
    }
};

// A few overloaded ostream operator<<()s for easy printing...
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const A& a ) {
    os << a.a;
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const B& b ) {
    os << b.b;
    return os;
}

template<typename T, typename U>
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const Pack<T,U>& pack ) {
    os << pack.getT() << " " << pack.getU() << '\n';
    return os;
}

// Main program to demonstrate its use
int main() {    
    Pack<int,double> p1( 1, 2.3 ), p2( 4, 9.2 ), p3( 5, 3.5 );        
    C<int, double> c( p1, p2, p3 );    
    for (auto& p : c.getPacks() )
        std::cout << p;

    std::cout << '\n'; 

    Pack<float, char> p4( 3.14f, 'a' ), p5( 6.95f, 'b' ),
                      p6( 2.81f, 'c' ), p7( 8.22f, 'd' );
    C<float, char> c2( p4, p5, p6, p7 );
    for ( auto& p : c2.getPacks() )
        std::cout << p;    

    return 0;
}
```

[Working Code](https://onlinegdb.com/rkrCRtTyN)

*-Output-*

```
1 2.3
4 9.2
5 3.5

3.14 a
6.95 b
2.81 c
8.22 d
```

---

*-Note-* I did not incorporate for any `odd` number of parameters. For a more detailed solution with odd cases you can refer to the other answers with `SFINAE` or `Delegating Constructor`.